# Android SQLite query: "queryNumEntries .. is not applicable for the arguments"?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database named `contacts.db` with a table named `TABLE_NAME` that has one column named `Contactname`. I want to format a query to check if a contact name that I have as a value in the String variable name is already saved as a record in the table and if it isn't then I want to add it, or else do nothing. The code that I wrote is as follows:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = events.getReadableDatabase();
int rawNum = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, TABLE_NAME, 
                        "Contactname=?", new String[] {contactName}); 
    if(rawNum==0){
        addRecord(contactName);
        addedCounter+=1;
    }
    else{
        savedCounter+=1;
    }
```

But the app is forced to close. Can you see anything wrong with the query? What I do is to see whether there are any rows and if the number of rows is 0 then to add the contact.

Comment: what fields does the table have?

Comment: Please post the logcat errors.

Comment: This can be written using a single SQL[ite] query: no need to check the results. Try searching for "the intent" on SO.

Comment: I get The method queryNumEntries(SQLiteDatabase, String) in the type DatabaseUtils is not applicable for the arguments (SQLiteDatabase, String, 
 String, String[])

Comment: That's a compile time error that says: I take `(SQLiteDatabase, String)`, but I was given `(SQLiteDatabase, String, String, String[])`. Time to go back to the API.

Comment: Method is overloaded and should accept those parameters: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html

Comment: @DavidCheung It's for a different class or a *different version* of the class then. Unpossible otherwise. (Going to "API Level 10" shows that it wasn't always around, for instance.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps it's time to update your development kit.

The method with the signature used in the code was introduced with API Level 11:

```
public static long queryNumEntries (SQLiteDatabase db, String table, String selection, String[] selectionArgs)
```

API Level 1 had only the two-argument method:

```
public static long queryNumEntries (SQLiteDatabase db, String table)
```